# Modal Popup on Window Exit

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

Trying to figure out how to make a modal pop up on browser window exit. I know how to do an alert box, but I want to have users answer a questionnaire on exit, instead of a basic "are you sure you want to leave" alert box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
  return 'Your content has not been properly saved yet!';
};
```

This will make the browser display a confirmation box like this one:

[image]

As you can see, the string returned by the function is shown in the box.

Comment: Is there anyway to edit the "stay on this page" and "leave this page" text?

Comment: You can't edit the button text for security reasons. You wouldn't want any old script kiddie have the ability to swap the yes/no buttons around so that you end up accepting malware be installed, for instance.

Comment: You won't be able to edit the dialog, but you can run basically any code in your function and it will be executed if the user decides to stay on your page. So you can call the code opening your dialog box/popup/whatever in onbeforeunload and ask your user to stay and see what you want to show him.

Note also, that if you care about IE < 8 you also need to set event.returnValue property.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The only way to stop the window from closing is to use the JS Confirm (or alert). If you were to just pop-up a modal in-page, the window would still close and you'd never see it. Your best bet is to open the JS alert, then redirect the page to the question. Though note that that is incredibly annoying for the user.

Comment: Ok, so would have to use a alert box and then ask them to stay of leave, if they leave could it then pop up a modal?

Comment: If they leave, they're gone, so no.

Comment: You have to bind to the document's `unload` event.

Comment: Ok, let's say if I give them two options: Leave - leaves site / Answer questions - popsup a modal

Comment: If they stay on the page, you could probably trigger a modal at that point. But if they leave, they've left.

Comment: You most definitely can give the user an option to stop the browser window from closing. Many websites use this technique in order for the user not to lose data. You can even see this used here on SO when you try to close the tab while typing in the reply box.

Answer (score 1):

While it is not always recommended to put code on exit, you could do something like this:

```
<body onUnload="javascript:openDialog()">
```

or

```
$(document).bind('unload', openDialog);
```

Then:

```
function openDialog(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#yourQuestionnaire").dialog('open');
}
```

**But generally it is a good practice to avoid binding to the `onUnload` event because its firing isn't reliable in all browsers and situations.**

**UPDATE**

The documentation shows it as:

```
$(window).unload(function() {
  alert('Handler for .unload() called.');
});
```

This works for me when applying it via the Firefox/Firebug console on any Stackoverflow page.

Documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/unload/

Comment: I don't think that will work. The window will still close whether or not there is a preventDefault on onunload, won't it?

Comment: This simply doesn't work. Any modern browser won't let you do that.

Comment: You're right, I have updated with a better solution and higlighted the section that warns against using it as it is generally not a good idea to bind to unload (as previously stated).

Answer (score 1):

I had similar requirements where I wanted to use nice HTML message instead of default js message. After spending some time I finally found a way to do it. I have used jQuery [Colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/) modal which is very useful in any modal requirement, not just here.

Basically you can use `mousemove` event and find if Y coordinate (`e.clientY` ) is less than 5. So it will be fired every time when mouse is near address bar (user typing new URL or trying to close window).

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery(document).mousemove(function(e) {
    if (e.clientY <= 5) {
        jQuery.colorbox({initialHeight: 250, initialWidth: 250, html:'<h2>any custom HTML here</h2><br/><img src="nice-img" />'});
    }
});
```

});

I found many example using `e.pageY` but note that it will only be fired if user has not scrolled down. So if you scroll down even for 5 pixel, `e.pageY` will not work, but `e.clientY` will work. 
`e.pageY` gives offset while `e.clientY` gives absolute coordinate. Very important!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple light-weight JQuery plugin that you could refer for your scenario
which tracks your mouse pointer and triggers the modal as soon as the mouse moves out of the viewport: [jQuery Exit Modal Plugin Example](https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Lightweight-Exit-Modal-Plugin-With-jQuery-And-Bootstrap-exit-modal.html)

```
$(window).on("unload",function() {
   alert("Handler for .unload() called");
});

NOTE: .unload() has been deprecated in version 1.8 and removed in jQuery 3.0; please 
use .on( "unload", handler ) instead of .unload( handler ).
```

See here : [unload(handler)](https://api.jquery.com/unload/#unload-handler)